# Is it possible that the initialisation fails, when creating an array with a size N

Tags: arrays, data-structures, memory-management

From what I understands, when I create a static array, say, `int[] array = new int[N];`, the run time actually looks for N*4 bytes of memory whose addresses are also continuous. right?

**So what if the run time can't find continuous memory addresses?**

for example, if my memory is 128MB, and in my application N = 25M, which means I need 100MB memory for my array. Is it possible for this creation of array to fail? Is it possible, the 100MB of memory in need can't be located because there are too many memory fragments?

thanks

Comment: What language? - I might have posted prematurely

Comment: @BrokenGlass Java, but I just try to understand generally how the memory management works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can fail. In that case an `OutOfMemoryException` will be thrown. An easy way to test this is the following:

```
int[] array = new int[int.MaxValue];
```

(This assumes C#, behavior in Java will be similar)

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking abut C++ (but is the same in general) arrays are contiguous, meaning that the memory has consecutive addresses, i.e. it's contiguous in virtual address space. It need not be contiguous in physical address space(programmers never sees an actual address of an array element, just a reference to the array and the means to index it).

Anyway if there is not memory available you will get an exception(it is not a contiguous matter)